# spring intergration large connections handling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

We have implemented tcp server with spring integration.

Configuration did as

```
@Bean
TcpNetServerConnectionFactory cf(){
    TcpNetServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(TCP_PORT);

    connectionFactory.setSerializer(new CustomSerializerDeserializer());
    connectionFactory.setDeserializer(new CustomSerializerDeserializer());
    connectionFactory.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
TcpInboundGateway tcpGate(){

    TcpInboundGateway gateway=new TcpInboundGateway();
    gateway.setConnectionFactory(cf());
    gateway.setRequestChannel(requestChannel());
    return gateway;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel requestChannel(){

    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

And service activator

```
@MessageEndpoint 
public class Echo {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="requestChannel")
    public byte[] echo(byte[] in,@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @Header("ip_address") String ip){

        return "OK".getBytes();
    }
}
```

We are having 150 + connections with assigned port and having 150+ tcp packet for every 10 seconds.

Currently we are dealing with late packet receiption issue, We required realtime data for our functioning.

Recently we conclude that threads are waiting for execution which results in late receiption of packet.

How can we handle this types of issue with spring integration and tcp inboudgateways.

Answer (score 2):

The `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` is a subclass of `AbstractConnectionFactory` which defines `java.util.concurrent.Executor` property (`taskExecutor`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does default task executor capable of handling large connections?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what _large_ means. Also, keep in mind, `Executor` simply executes tasks. It in itself has no relation to connections of any kind.

Comment: Okay. Let me explain the scenario : We have 150+ connections over TCP port and each client send data packet for every 10 seconds, We have observed that data packets received at service activator are late enough than expected time. Delay time increased as load increased.

Comment: Let me try it differently. You are describing _a scenario_ where it appears that introducing higher level of concurrency may help, hence I am suggesting adding an executor (e.g.. `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`) with higher thread pool. Now, that in itself may not help as it depends on many factors (both hardware and software). I don't know those factors, as I don;'t know your environment, so I can't speculate any further. Saying something is 'large' in this context is meaningless.

Comment: instead of large we can say it as too many connections. not an issue, thank you for help. I will try to implement CompositeExecutor for this scenario. If you know about it, please help us out.

Comment: Try using the `TcpNioServerConnectionFactory` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Us the `TcpNioServerConnectionFactory` instead; the `...Net...` is more efficient for a small number of long-lasting connections.

But see [this chapter in the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#note_nio).

Comment: Thank you Gary. Does default task executor capable to handle any number of request or do we need to add custom task executor?

Comment: Yes; the default task executor has unlimited threads, so that shouldn't be a problem with either connection factory. You don't really describe the nature of your "late packets" but bear in mind there is much more involved than just handling the socket IO, if CPUs are busy processing messages from other sockets, for example, or perhaps there is some code synchronization that is causing a bottleneck. You need to look at your CPU usage and/or profile your application to figure out why it is not handling the message rate you need. 15 messages per second is a very low message rate.

Comment: You are right connection issue might not be there. I guess packet processing might be having time consuming process. We are using custom serializer and deserializer for packet differentiation and also used direct channel, will it be the cause for late receiption of data?

Comment: I have no idea about your code, you will have to profile it; the DirectChannel adds very little overhead.